# Why the oracle query is slow in java but much faster when it is just directly executed in sqlDeveloper?

Tags: java, oracle, performance

I have around 100k records in the db table and when I execute this query in oracle sqlDeveloper, it takes around 33 seconds to fetch the 100k records.

```
select wflworkflo1_.REF_ID from ( select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_HISTORYSTEP WHERE START_DATE < to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy') UNION ALL select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_CURRENTSTEP WHERE START_DATE < to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy')) wflworkflo1_ WHERE REF_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT REF_ID FROM (select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_HISTORYSTEP WHERE START_DATE >= to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy') UNION ALL select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_CURRENTSTEP WHERE START_DATE >= to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy')) INT_WFL GROUP BY REF_ID) group by wflworkflo1_.REF_ID having max(wflworkflo1_.START_DATE) < to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

In my java program, this is the method to run the query.

```
public List<String> findCurrHistStepRefIdWithStartDate(String targetStartDate)
        throws BocException {
    
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append(
            "select wflworkflo1_.REF_ID from ( select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_HISTORYSTEP WHERE START_DATE < to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy') UNION ALL select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_CURRENTSTEP WHERE START_DATE < to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) wflworkflo1_ WHERE REF_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT REF_ID FROM (select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_HISTORYSTEP WHERE START_DATE >= to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy') UNION ALL select REF_ID, START_DATE from OS_CURRENTSTEP WHERE START_DATE >= to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) INT_WFL GROUP BY REF_ID) group by wflworkflo1_.REF_ID having max(wflworkflo1_.START_DATE) < to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy')");
    
    JdbcTemplate template = getJdbcTemplate();
    
    return template.queryForList(sql.toString(), String.class,
            targetStartDate, targetStartDate, targetStartDate, targetStartDate,
            targetStartDate);

}
```

This Java function takes more than 1 hour to return the result. Why is there such a huge difference?

Comment: 1) Try inlining the date parameter so that the query strings are identical.  2) Is it the same database on the same database server via the same network path ... in both cases?

Comment: @StephenC Yes same database, same server, same network path.. In the java program, it actually pass in the same 20/09/2023 date parameter too.

Comment: You need to capture two execution plans when the query is running: one for SQL Developer version and another for Java version. See [`dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690).

Comment: @DavidHolly Are you sure that SQL Developer is returning all 100K records, and not just the top N rows?

Comment: Are you pointing to remote db server from you local java environment while running the query directly inside the remote db?

Comment: @hermit yes.. am pointing to remote db from local java environment

Comment: Pointing from local java code to remote db is inherently slow because your local code needs to setup connection to the remote server and fetch data from it. For example, pointing to the db in  staging environment from local will lead to large query execution time.

But, when you run the sql query directly, you are logging in to the server and running your query there. So, it is faster.

But, when your code gets deployed to staging, the execution time will significantly improve given that your application and db are hosted in the same environment, e.g. staging.

Comment: @hermit - that doesn't explain a 33 secs vs 1 hour difference.

Comment: @StephenC Agreed. It might not be the sole reason, but, we cannot rule out the fact that it might have played some role in aggravating the delay.

Comment: @DavidHolly If it is possible, could you please try deploying the code in the same env as the db and observe the execution time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting the joins to analytic functions should avoid most potential database problems. Since the rewritten query has no joins, there are very few ways the execution plan can go wrong. As an added bonus, the new code is smaller and arguably simpler.

```
-- ref_ids that only have old data.
select distinct ref_id
from
(
    --all data along with counts of new dates per ref_id.
    select ref_id, start_date,
        sum(case when start_date >= to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy') then 1 else 0 end) 
        over (partition by ref_id) new_dates_per_ref_id
    from
    (
        --all data
        select ref_id, start_date from os_historystep
        union all
        select ref_id, start_date from os_currentstep
    )
)
where start_date < to_date('20/09/2023' , 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    and new_dates_per_ref_id = 0;
```

However, this answer is merely a workaround. You may want to dig into the execution plans and find out why this problem is happening. To do that, I recommend you follow astentx's advice and use [dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690). But solving difficult Oracle performance problems can take a long time, so there's nothing wrong with just avoiding the problem if you don't have hours to spend on query tuning.